# How open local authority file with java android

Tags: java, android

Please help me

I have a local LAN...

```
LAN NAME = " XXX " 
LAN PASSWORD =" 12345 "
```

And I have NT server (it does not support HTTP server)

```
Server IP is = 192.168.1.222 
Server name is = "SERVER"
```

My server is secured. And I logged in with user="*tayfur*" pass="*abcd*".

Finally; I want to open `\\SERVER\YEDEK\olc1.jpg` with Android device.

How connect to file with Java for Android (I use eclipse)? Please send me 
examples.